# The best way of using maps in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

In apex/visualforce I can use `Map<String, List<SelectOption>>` but in Lightning I can't use iteration with maps. What is the best of using maps in lightning? Wrapper class? Or lists with key, value?

Comment: Map works in lightning. They behave same as JSON objects or array depending on situation. SelectOption class provides some benefits for visualforce but under the hood its a wrapper class. Best would be to use Map<String, List<Wrapper> as you’d be sure of the structure.

Comment: @RahulSharma could you expand your comment as an answer by providing an example if you have one?

Comment: There is different way to do this depending on what you are trying to achieve. Would be nice if you could show us what you have so far. If that can inspire you : http://www.sfdcmonkey.com/2017/01/13/iterate-map-values-lightning-component/